# Python Amazon scraping using headers

Tags: python, python-3.x, http-headers

I am making a Python script to get information from Amazon by parsing the page's HTML. I had the following code, which wouldn't work:

```
import requests
url = "http://www.amazon.com/"
text = requests.get(url)
print(text)
```

This code raised `HTTPError: HTTP Error 503: Service Temporarily Unavailable` .
Then I found the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23555283/why-cant-i-scrape-amazon-by-beautifulsoup) and now the code looks like this:

```
import requests
url = "http://www.amazon.com/"
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/54.0.2840.71 Safari/537.36'}
text = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
print(text)
```

which works. I understand that the purpose of the `header` argument to the `get` function is so that Amazon thinks the HTTP request is coming from a browser.

Now to my question - is there any other way to have access to Amazon without using this (what looks like) a "dirty trick"?

Also, is it "ethical" to do this? I was looking into using this script for personal use or to integrate it as a function in a Discord bot, but before I go any further I want to be sure I'm not doing something questionable here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**NO, IT IS NOT ETHICAL !!!**

1. that is why you have to mention user agent in header.
2. here you can read as they are clearly mentioning it [Amazon's Conditions of Use](https://www.amazon.com/gp/help/customer/display.html/ref=hp_left_v4_sib?ie=UTF8&nodeId=201909000)

this is mentioned under ADDITIONAL AMAZON SOFTWARE TERMS heading

> You may not incorporate any portion of the Amazon Software into other programs or compile any portion of it in combination with other programs, or otherwise copy (except to exercise rights granted in this section), modify, create derivative works of, distribute, assign any rights to, or license the Amazon Software in whole or in part

3. However you can look at API provided by Amazon [Developer Documentation](https://developer.amazon.com/documentation/) it may help you !!!
4. The another reason is doing such things brings loads on the servers which kinda costs them huge, for no profit of them.
5. you might have more follow up questions if so can read [this](https://sellercentral.amazon.com/forums/t/amazon-web-scraping/153134/11) thread as well for more queries

Comment: Thank you for the reply. You have answered my question. However, if you would, I still have a doubt. If I were to build some sort of bot for a platform like Discord, it'd basically be free publicity for them. Is the best option to email some service of them and ask about it? It would appear the Amazon API only lets you do one request per second, which would render it unusable if only a few people were using it.

Comment: Glad to help !!! :),  yes It is always good to ask before jumping into it, also don't forget to look into there terms of services and developer API's, read it you may get asked counter questions so you will be in position to answer them..

Answer (score 0):

Can you agree to terms and conditions from scraping?  You're not on the platform.  So far as I can tell, they may try to block requests but that is an attempt, if you bypass that, I don't understand the maliciousness.  You didn't necessarily agree to anything.  So if they can't keep external traffic out, it seems to be moreso on them.